# Spring data JPA repository : find query throw OptimisticLocking exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

can i ask about opt locking.
can read operation in spring data JPA like repository.findOne(), findById throwing OptimisticLocking. ?

i'm using spring-data jpa + hibernate + mysql

```
Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [com.sample.persistence.domain.Driver#540444464]; nested exception is javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [com.sample.persistence.domain.Driver#540444464]"
```

thanks

[code]
persistence

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "driver")
public class Driver extends Base {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "phone", length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String phone;

    @Column(name = "photograph")
    private String photograph;

}


@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Base implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7369920601847524273L;

    public Base() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Integer id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "date_last_modified")
    protected Date modificationDate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "date_created")
    protected Date creationDate;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    protected Integer version;
}
```

repository

```
@Repository
public interface DriverRepository extends JpaRepository<Driver, Integer>, DriverRepositoryCustom, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Driver> {
}
```

DAO code

```
public Driver findById(Integer key) {

        Driver driver = driverRepository.findOne(key);
        if (driver == null) {
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @NguyenTuanAnh , thats my sniplet code

Comment: Could you post complete dao code and steps to reproduce?

Comment: It's related to the `@Version`, I don't think this happens when you're retrieving an entity.  You're trying to execute an update but the version in the row and the entity you're merging doesn't match.

Comment: As others pointed out, post the implementation of `findOne(key)` method until the call to the entity manager. The code you posted cannot throw this exception.